# gulpif doesn't work with del

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-if

with this code:

```
 global.release = argv.release;
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
    var del = require('del');

    module.exports = gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
        return gulpif(release, del([TMP_FOLDER, PHONEGAP_FOLDER],cb), del([TMP_FOLDER, BUILD_FOLDER],cb));
    });
```

I've got this error:

```
[14:07:35] Starting 'default'...
[14:07:35] Starting 'clean'...
undefined
[14:07:35] 'clean' errored after 6.11 ms
[14:07:35] Error: gulp-if: child action is required
    at module.exports (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp-if/index.js:10:9)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/gulp/tasks/clean.js:8:12)
    at module.exports (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:74:16)
    at runSequence (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:85:2)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/gulp/tasks/default.js:15:9)
    at module.exports (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
Error running task sequence: { task: 'clean',
  message: 'clean catch',
  duration: 0.006112762,
  hrDuration: [ 0, 6112762 ],
  err: [Error: gulp-if: child action is required] }
[14:07:35] Finished 'default' after 13 ms
[14:07:35] 'clean' errored after 15 ms
[14:07:35] Error: task completion callback called too many times
    at finish (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:15:10)
    at cb (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at module.exports (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/each-async/index.js:22:3)
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/index.js:34:3
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:277:13
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:17
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/index.js:38:4
    at f (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/glob.js:129:7)
[14:07:35] 'clean' errored after 16 ms
[14:07:35] Error: task completion callback called too many times
    at finish (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:15:10)
    at cb (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at module.exports (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/each-async/index.js:22:3)
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/index.js:34:3
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:277:13
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:17
    at /home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/index.js:38:4
    at f (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/user/github/angular-bootstrap-cordova-seed/node_modules/del/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/glob.js:129:7)
```

is it a bug ?
if not what's the matter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- you are trying to use gulp-if outside of vinyl stream
- del isn't gulp-plugin.

You don't need gulp-if for your example:

```
module.exports = gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  del(release ? [TMP_FOLDER, PHONEGAP_FOLDER] : [TMP_FOLDER, BUILD_FOLDER], cb);
});
```

https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if

> A ternary gulp plugin: conditionally control the flow of vinyl objects.